# Javascript font size changes from win 10 to win 11

Tags: java, windows

We have a large Java application that looks fine with Win 10. When we test it on Win 11, about 1/2 the controls have a much smaller font than the others.

This is using the same version of the Open JDK Java 11 VM on both machines.

My searches haven't found anything, but it seems odd that it would only be our Java app with this issue.

At one time I did have a tool that let me just click on a java application window/control and see all the information about it (colors, font size, etc..). That was years ago, and I can't seem to find one that does that now.

Any ideas on why some fonts would change size on Win 11?

Comment: You will need to read each line into a `std::string` with `getline()` and create a `std::stringstream` from the string containing the line and then read from the `std::stringstream` with `getline()` using the delimiter or `','` and keep track of the number of columns and sum the ones you need. Please add the code showing what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different things that you need to understand. For example:

Data, belonging together, but having a different type, will be stored in a class or struct.

Many data of the same type, will be stored in an array or in this example in a `std::vector` because that can grow dynamically.

So, as you already did, you will put the data of one row or, in database language, of one record, in a struct.

So, your approach is correct, to define the TaxPayer class. But now, because you want to accumulate the sum of one data field of many TaxPayers, you need to put all the TaxPayers in a `std::vector` and encapsulate this in a second class. Then you add additional functions to that class, to calculate sums of the records (TaxPayer) in the `std::vector`.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct TaxPayer {
    std::string taxpayerId{};
    std::string name{};
    std::string address{};
    std::string postcode{};
    int salary{};
    int deductions{};
    double taxDue{};
};
struct TaxPayers {
    std::vector<TaxPayer> taxPayers{};
};
```

I just show the data members here. And you may reuse your existing functions of course.

Now, we just need to add basically 2 important functions:

1. Split one source row into its elements and then assign it to the taxPayer data fields
2. Read all taxPayers

The task number one is splitting so called CSV (Comma Separated Values) data. You will find at least 1000 examples here on stackoverflow on how to do this. A very popular method is to use `std::getline` and read a part of the text until the separator ','.

To be more on the save side, first a complete line of the source file is read via `std::getline`. Then, this will be put into a `stringstream` and the further extraction of data is done from there.

All this will be embedded in an overwritten "extraction" operator `>>`, that handles your specific data.

The signature of such an operator is:

```
friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, TaxPayer& tp)
```

After implementation of the functionality, you can simply use the `>>` operator, to read a complete row and parse it in one step.

In you TaxPayers class you need to define also such an operator and read all lines using the extractor from the definition above.

By this method, by splitting a big task into smaller tasks, the solution will get very simple at the end.

Last but not least, we need to add you accumulation functions of the data in the `std::vector`. That can be either done with a simple loop, or, a little bit more advanced, with `std::accumulate`.

You may use the below example as an idea to refactor cour existing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct TaxPayer {
    // Data part
    std::string taxpayerId{};
    std::string name{};
    std::string address{};
    std::string postcode{};
    int salary{};
    int deductions{};
    double taxDue{};

    // Extractor
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, TaxPayer& tp) {
        // Read a complete line
        std::string line{};
        if (std::getline(is, line) and not line.empty()) {


            // Put it into a stringstream for further extraction
            std::istringstream iss{ line };

            // Now, extract the data parts
            std::getline(iss, tp.taxpayerId, ',');
            std::getline(iss, tp.name, ',');
            std::getline(iss, tp.address, ',');
            std::getline(iss, tp.postcode, ',');

            // Read and convert
            std::getline(iss, line, ',');
            tp.salary = std::stoi(line);

            std::getline(iss, line, ',');
            tp.deductions = std::stoi(line);

            std::getline(iss, line, ',');
            tp.taxDue = std::stod(line);
        }
        return is;
    }
    // Simple inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const TaxPayer& tp) {
        return os << tp.taxpayerId << ' ' << tp.name << ' ' << tp.address << ' ' << tp.postcode
            << ' ' << tp.salary << ' ' << tp.deductions << ' ' << tp.taxDue << '\n';
    }

};
struct TaxPayers {
    // Data
    std::vector<TaxPayer> taxPayers{};

    // Sum functions
    int sumSalary() {
        int result{};
        for (const TaxPayer& taxPayer : taxPayers)
            result += taxPayer.salary;
        return result;
    }
    int sumDeductions() {
        int result{};
        for (const TaxPayer& taxPayer : taxPayers)
            result += taxPayer.deductions;
        return result;
    }

    // Extractor
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, TaxPayers& tp) {
        // clar old data
        tp.taxPayers.clear();

        // Read all new existing data and store in vector
        TaxPayer taxPayer{};

        while (is >> taxPayer)
            tp.taxPayers.push_back(taxPayer);
        return is;
    }
    // Simple inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const TaxPayers& tp) {
        for (const TaxPayer& taxPayer : tp.taxPayers)
            os << taxPayer;
        return os;
    }


};

// Same as a file, I just use it here for better visibility
std::istringstream sourceFile{ R"(7101003,Mike,23 boinig road,2615,48000,12000,0
7201003,Jane Philips,29 boinig cresent,2616,47000,12000,0
7301003,Philip Jane,23 bong road,2615,49000,000,0
7401004,Peta,23 bong bong road,2615,148000,19000,0
7101205,Abdulla,23 Station st,2615,80000,21000,0)" };

int main() {

    TaxPayers taxPayers{};

    // Read and parse all tax payers
    sourceFile >> taxPayers;

    // Debug output: Show, what we just read
    std::cout << taxPayers;

    // Show sums
    std::cout << "\n\n\nSummary\n\nSalary:\t\t" << taxPayers.sumSalary() << "\nDeductions:\t" << taxPayers.sumDeductions() << '\n';
}
```